# RhinoMock - Recursive mocking

Tags: rhino-mocks

I am not able to get the recursive mocking to work.

```
SomeClass someMOck = MockRepository.GenerateMock<SomeClass>();

//SomeClass is having another class as a property.

someMock.Stub(x => x.Manager.SomeData).Return("Hello");
```

During runtime it throws an error.

System.InvalidOperationException : Previous method
'SomeClass.get_Manager();' requires a return value or an
exception to throw.

I am using 3.6 build 21.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

This is because you don't have a value specified for `someeClass.Manager`.

You will need to mock the `Manager` class and set that as the return value for `someeClass.Manager`.

```
SomeClass someMock= MockRepository.GenerateMock<SomeClass>();
Manager managerMock= MockRepository.GenerateMock<Manager>(); 

managerMock.Stub(x => x.SomeData).Return("Hello");
someMock.Stub(x => x.Manager).Return(managerMock);
```

But another thing has to do with the design of your code. The [Law Of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) states that you shouldn't use nested property.property in your code. You should only pass in the information that is really necessary and make sure that everything that is passed in is used. So is it really necessary to access a complete `Manager` object only to get to `SomeData`?

Comment: I do understand the Law of Demeter. But the idea is to see if we can do some testing without changing /refactoring. But the thing is if I want to do the recursive mocking I need to stub out anyway right. I was under the impression that RhinoMock will do it automatically.

Comment: But even after stubbing I am not sure why this syntax wont work x=> x.Manager.SoemData 'x.Manager' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'. RhinoMocks documentation says we can use this syntax as part of the new recursive mocking.